# How can I have a mutually exclusive column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im not sure the best way to phrase this, so let me illustrate:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  enum state: [:active, :inactive]
end
```

If I update any foo to be `:active`, I need to change all other Foos in the same organization to be `:inactive`.

But, I don't want to be too eager about this, in case the Foo being changed to active fails some sort of validation or otherwise gets rolled back. On the flip side, I can't have two Foos be `:active` at the same time.

I plan to send out notifications in after_commit hooks. But if I update the `:active` models to be `:inactive` inside of of an after_update hook, then I don't know if the after_commit hooks will be fired for those models while still inside of the main transaction or not.

Comment: so your question is how to use `transaction` in Rails?

Comment: Sorry, no. I just realized I left some info out. Basically, this could all almost work except I don't know what happens when with the after_commit callbacks when nested inside a transaction.

Comment: I think instead of using `state` column in `foos` table, a `active_foo_id` column in `organizations` would be better :) You only need to update another record when you want to change the state of one `foo`

Comment: I think that would work! There are actually more than two states in my application, so that has to stay, but I can tolerate brief inconsistencies in my foos table if I use the organization as the authoritative source of what is active. Thanks!

Comment: Can I post this as an answer for your question?

Comment: It's Stack Overflow, of course you can :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there will be instances when you'll be violating your unique-constraint and apply it only after some checks, I wouldn't recommend looking into database constraints / conditional unique indexes, unless you absolutely want to tackle race conditions.

I think if you put something like the following in your model, it should work:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # the following should be your last callback
  after_update :unique_state

  # replacing the enum with an easy-to-understand scope
  scope :active, -> { where(state: true) }

  private

  def unique_state
    # do nothing if state is false:
    return unless state

    Foo
    .active
    .where(organization_id: organization_id)
    .where.not(id: id)
    .update_all(state: false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy my comment above as an answer for your question:

I think instead of using `state` column in `foos` table, an `active_foo_id` column in `organizations` would be better :) You only need to update one record when you want to change the state.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by changing the column to a Datetime named `active_as_of`. Making a particular record as active is achieved via a simple `touch(:active_as_of)`, and the potential for multiple active records is eliminated.

This also resolves the case where the active record is deleted or deactivated. The most-recently active record would, in this case, resume its active status without interruption.